# Ensuring columns start with a header tag

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have a long list of mixed attributes that look little like this:

```
<h3>Section Title</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
<h3>Section Title</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Because the html is generated by a client using a CMS, I have no control over how many sections there will be, or how many items will show in each section. I do have control over the html output and all front-end technologies, etc that the CMS uses.

We want to break this list into 3 columns of (approximately) equal height, and the most effective way seems to be CC3 columns.

**How can we ensure that each new column starts with a header?** 
At present the column could break in the middle of a list, which is not desired behaviour.

Comment: If you have control over the output, will you be able to add the h3 as the first element to the list?  Something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Htv7Id8CDK

Comment: What do you mean by "_I do have control over the html output_"? (Could you change the HTML structure above?) And are you looking at a pure-CSS solution or JavaScript (as a front-end technology) is an option?

Comment: By that, I mean I can control anything up to the point the project is handed over. At that point, the end user might have 10 categories with 100 items each; or 100 items. So we need a solution that will be adaptive over time. 

(Obviously, if it becomes huge, it'll need the information architecture rethought, but this one page/3 column solution should be suitable within the limits we're imagining.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to wrap each section within a container (I'll use a `<div>`, but you may want to use a `<section>`), and then specify the styling for that container so it doesn't break between columns.

From an extension  of your original code (I wrapped everything in a `div` for convenience, added the styling to display it in 3 columns, and a few more sections to show the effect):

```css
div#myDiv {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    
    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
    
    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
    
    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
    
    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
    
</div>
```

You can do this in two different ways:

**Option 1: If you can change the HTML structure**

As you mentioned "*I do have control over the html output*", wrap all the sections in a `<div>` and apply this style to make sure that each section is treated as a block and won't be broken into different columns:

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

The final code would look like:

```css
div#myDiv {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
#myDiv div {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <div>
         <h3>Section Title</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
         <h3>Section Title</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
         <h3>Section Title</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
         <h3>Section Title</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
         <h3>Section Title</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
         <h3>Section Title</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
         <h3>Section Title</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
         <h3>Section Title</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
         <h3>Section Title</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also see it on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4jLgfo1/

**Option 2: If you cannot change the HTML, but can run JS**

As you mentioned that you could run all front-end technologies, JavaScript (and jQuery for convenience) is one :)

Same CSS code as above, but now run a small JavaScript snippet to wrap the sections once the HTML is generated and served:

```js
$("#myDiv h3").wrap("<div></div>");
$("#myDiv div").each(function() {
    $(this).append($(this).next());
});
```

```css
div#myDiv {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
#myDiv div {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
    
    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
    
    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
    
    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
    
    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Section Title</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
    
</div>
```

You can also see it on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4jLgfo1/1/

Comment: Awesome. By using inline-block for each child to stop them being broken, we can do just what we need without adding extra js. However, I tested that option too, and it would also achieve what we need.